# Создание селектора

Tags: css-selectors, css

Здравствуйте. Есть приблизительно такая разметка:

```
<ul id="root">
  <li><span class='amazing'><a href="#">Link1</a></span></li>
  <li><h1><a href="#">Link2</a><h1></li>
  <li>
    <a href="#">Link3</a>
    <ul>
      <li><a href="#">Link31</a></li>
      <li><h3><a href="#">Link32</a></h3></li>
      <li><a href="#">Link33</a></li>
    </ul>
  </li>
</ul>
```

Как создать селектор, позволяющий найти только те теги `<a></a>`, которые находятся в ul#root и не находятся во вложенных `<ul>`-ах (то есть выделить Link1, Link2 и Link3, а Link31, Link32 и Link33 "не заметить")?

Comment: я так понимаю, здесь есть только вариант "задать всем и отменить ненужным"

    ul#root li a {
        // определяем необходимое
    }

    ul#root ul a {
        // обнуляем правила для лишних ссылок
    }

Лично я бы решил проблему проставляением классов нужным ссылкам на сервере

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[Такой вариант](http://jsfiddle.net/Deonis/LdXrG/) подойдет, если ссылка в <li> присутствует в единичном экземпляре:

```
$('#root > li').find('a:first').css('color','red');
```

Comment: С jquery это работает. А в css только классы?

Comment: @alvoro, если уж извращаться, то по полной )) [Смотрим тут][1]

    #root > li > *:not(ul) a,
    #root > li > a {
        color: #f00;
    }

P.S. Меня, кстати, сбили с толку предыдущие ответы и я думал, что надо именно для jQuery селектор подобрать.

   [1]:http://jsfiddle.net/Deonis/LdXrG/1/

Comment: Вот теперь вообще сказка. Спасибо.

Answer (score 2):

```
$("ul#root > li a")
```

Comment: Рано обрадовался. Оно же все равно выделяет те <a>, что не надо.

    ul#root > li a {
      background: red;
    }

Comment: В CSS этот селектор подходит для всех ссылок из данного примера.

Comment: Ну да, правильно. А мне надо что бы `<a>`, которые находятся в `<ul id!=root>` не выделялись.

Comment: тогда такой ul#root > li > a, ul#root > li h1 a, ul#root > li span a

Comment: тоже самое, что предлагал @Дмитрий Клименко (его ответ ниже).

> Тут вся фишка в том, что я не знаю как глубоко и во что будет "зарыта" ссылка.

Comment: можно тогда с переопределением
ul#root > li a{color: red;}
ul#root ul > li a{color: black;}

Answer (score 1):

```
/*Link1*/#root>li span a {}
/*Link2*/#root>li h1 a {}
/*Link3*/#root>li>a {}
```

/*или*/

```
/*Link1*/#root li:nth-child(1) a {}
/*Link2*/#root li:nth-child(2) a {}
/*Link3*/#root li:nth-child(3)>a {}
```

Comment: Тут вся фишка в том, что я не знаю как далеко и во что будет "зарыта" ссылка.